# AppleScript with Mail, reply to email, can't set content

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, scripting-bridge

I can correctly create a brand new outgoing message in Mail, and set its body.

However, when I try to use the `replyOpeningWindow:replyToAll:` method (called on an existing mail message), I cannot set the content. Calling `setContent:` on the resultant `MMOutgoingMessage` seems to do nothing, the content of the message remains as the quoted text of the message I'm replying to.

Has anyone successfully used `replyOpeningWindow:replyToAll:` and then changed properties on the resultant email message?

**Edit to add:**

This problem isn't a Scripting Bridge issue. The same problem occurs with this AppleScript:

```
tell application "Mail"
    copy first message of inbox to emailMessage
    set replyMessage to reply emailMessage without opening window
    set content of replyMessage to "Hello"
    set visible of replyMessage to true
end tell
```

Comment: Interestingly, I've just tried this AppleScript code in MacOS 10.12 and it works. Can anyone else confirm that this is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change certain properties of a reply message, including content.

Comment: Do you know if this is documented anywhere? (I don't think you're wrong, but it would be nice to know if it was a bug or intentional!)

Comment: I haven't seen it documented other than through the many complaints in the forums over several years.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. If you add a delay before setting the content, it works.

```
tell application "Mail"
copy first message of inbox to emailMessage
set replyMessage to reply emailMessage without opening window
delay 0.1
set content of replyMessage to "Hello"
set visible of replyMessage to true
end tell
```